# Difference in foreign key constraint violation error between local MySQL database and server MySQL database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have two databases created using the same script, once on the server, and once on my local machine.

On both, I try to add a row in a table, with one column referencing a foreign key of another table for which the referenced ID does not exist yet.

On my local machine, I get this error: `ERROR 1452: 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails [info on which foreign key violation here]`

On the server, I get this error: `ERROR 1216: 1216: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`

Note the different error codes, and also the server does not specify which foreign key constraint is violated.

My local MySQL version: `8.0.27 (Windows machine)`

Server MySQL version: `8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2`

What could be causing the difference?

I would like my server to tell me which foreign key constraint is being violated so I can debug errors. Am I missing a config?

(Both queries were done using MySQL Workbench 8.0CE, also using .Net Core EntityFramework for MySQL with same results)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per mysql manual on [foreign keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> If a user has table-level privileges for all parent tables, ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2 and ER_ROW_IS_REFERENCED_2 error messages for foreign key operations expose information about parent tables. If a user does not have table-level privileges for all parent tables, more generic error messages are displayed instead (ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW and ER_ROW_IS_REFERENCED).

[ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html#error_er_no_referenced_row) maps to 1216, while [ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html#error_er_no_referenced_row_2) maps to 1452 error messages. So, you need to have access to all affected tables in order to get 1452 error message. This makes sense from a security point of view.